# Read only parameter name in Querystring with $_GET

Tags: php, parameters, get, query-string

How can I read only the parameter name from a querystring in PHP? For example in both of these:

```
www.example.com/index.php?a='1'
www.example.com/index.php?a
```

the wanted output is:

```
a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) of the global $_GET array:

```
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
echo $keys[0]; // echos a
```

Answer (score 2):

You need get a key of a GET:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val)
{
    print($key);
}
```

Or a get via `print_r(array_keys($_GET));` function.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` is just an array variable (not command). It is populated with parameter names as keys in this array, and parameter values as the corresponding values.

So just use `array_keys($_GET)`.